# imprimir total de registros en bd

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

tengo una duda y espero puedan ayudarme con mi consulta, resulta que estoy haciendo un Panel de administracion y ocupo imprimir en un widget del dashboard el total de usuarios que hay registrados y lo logre pero me interesa mostrar la suma de los registros que van del dia, no el total que hay en la base de datos,  como haria esto? espero puedan apoyarme

PD:En la Bd esta la columna Created_At en la cual se inserta la fecha y hora en que se registro un nuevo usuario.

El controler "DashboardController":

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Job;
use App\JobApplication;
use App\Payment;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard(){

        $data = [
            'usersCount' => User::count(),    
        ];


        return view('admin.dashboard', $data);
    }
}
```

e imprimo la variable como:

```
{{$usersCount}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con Carbon tienes la solución a la mano, utiliza el método today() para la comparación, dicho método entrega la fecha de hoy y la hora en 00:00:00

```
User::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->count();
```

Recuerda incluir Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Comment: Y como puedo obtener solo la fecha sin la hora, porque no coincide el formato  que imprime Carbon con el que tengo en la bd

Comment: ¿Qué formato tienes acaso?

Comment: en la bd tengo Y-m-d h:i:s y el carbon imprime Y-m-d pero la hora en 00:00:00 por lo que no coincide y al entrar un nuevo registro no lo contempla porque no coinciden por formato

Comment: No entiendo por qué no te sirve si la comparación es mayor o igual, a mi me funciona perfectamente en varios proyectos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar whereDate y Carbon:

```
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    ....
    $data = [
            'usersCount' => User::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->count(),    
    ];
```

---

**EDIT**

También puedes usar CURDATE de Mysql

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
....
$data = [
    'usersCount' => User::whereDate('created_at', DB::raw('CURDATE()'))->count();
];
```

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta que me ha funcionado de igual forma

Comment: Y como puedo obtener solo la fecha sin la hora, porque no coincide el formato que imprime Carbon con el que tengo en la bd

Comment: @AbdielHernandez por lo que comentas, el formato es el mismo, solo que Carbon->today te da 00:00:00 (h:i:s) porque es a la hora que comienza el día, whereDate() no toma en cuenta h:m:s. Se me ocurre que la base de datos y la app pueden estar usando distintas zonas horarias y eso haría que a ciertas horas las pase para el día anterior o siguiente, puedes probar eso, mira el edit en la respuesta.